# DATABRICKS connect 6.4 not able to communicate with server anymore

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I am running Pycharm on my MacBook.

Client settings:
Python Interpreter ->  Python 3.7 (dtabricks-connect-6.4)

Cluster settings:
Databricks Runtime Version -> 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

It worked well for months but suddenly, without any updates made, I cant run  my python script from Pycharm against databricks cluster anymore.
The Error is ...

```
Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The cluster is running server version `dbr-6.4` but this client only supports Set(dbr-5.5)....`
```

I restarted Pycharm, I witched back and for the interpreter, I restarted the cluster and I even restarted my MacBook but it didnt helped. The Error message is simply false, because both,  cluster and client are using the SAME version. I can see that when I execute my python script that the cluster is being started but fails at the end.

```
pyenv activate databricks-connect-6-4

pip freeze

Cython==0.29.21
databricks-connect==6.4.0
numpy==1.19.2
pandas==1.0.1
py4j==0.10.7
pyarrow==0.13.0
pycountry==20.7.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I deinstalled and installed databricks-connect==6.4 but it didnt helped. I tried to perform databricks-connect test with the same result. It seems to me that databricks itself did some changes without noticing us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that it was caused by some internal changes on the server side, and this prevents databricks-connect from working.   You can always disable this check by setting environment variable `DEBUG_IGNORE_VERSION_MISMATCH` to value `1` (`export DEBUG_IGNORE_VERSION_MISMATCH=1` in the console before executing `databricks-connect test`) - you can also set this environment variable in the PyCharm.

Update: it should be fixed by [Databricks Connect 6.4.2](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-connect/6.4.2/) that was just released.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising this. The Databricks-Connect team has acknowledged this issue and we are working on a patch to address this issue. Will keep you posted. In the meantime you can use the `DEBUG_IGNORE_VERSION_MISMATCH` as Alex pointed out.

**Update**: A compatible db-connect client has been released to fix this problem: version 6.4.2 (https://pypi.org/project/databricks-connect/6.4.2/, install with: pip install databricks-connect==6.4.2).